# How to make the function reusable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and the property are id and name. 
Now I have a function that checks the duplicate value of id and name.
My problem is I make the function redundant. I want to use the code only once to make it as reusable.

The only difference is the property name. Are there any solution to use the function only once? Thanks

```js
var data = [{id: 0, name: "lina"},  {id: 1, name: "jona"}, {id: 2, name: "lina"}, {id: 0},{id: 3, name: "anna"}];

function isDuplicateID() {            
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].id === 0)
      continue;
    for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if(data[j].id === data[i].id)
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function isDuplicateName() {            
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].name === 0)
      continue;
    for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if(data[j].name === data[i].name)
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

alert(isDuplicateID())
alert(isDuplicateName())
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740869/how-to-check-duplicates-in-array-except-0-javascript) (from OP)

Answer (score 2):

Properties in javascript can be get by either using `obj.propName` or `obj[propName]`.

```js
var data = [{id: 0, name: "lina"},  {id: 1, name: "jona"}, {id: 2, name: "lina"}, {id: 0},{id: 3, name: "anna"}];
function isDuplicate(propName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][propName] === 0)
            continue;
        for (var j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (data[j][propName] === data[i][propName])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(isDuplicate("id"))
alert(isDuplicate("name"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add parameter `key` and use it. Following code depicts the same

```
function isDuplicateID(key) {            
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][key] === 0)
      continue;
    for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if(data[j][key] === data[i][key])
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using . to access properties you can enclosed the property name in square brackets, ie instead of . you can use [].

This means you can then pass in the property name, one of the great features of javascript.

```
function isDuplicate(propertyName) {            
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][propertyName] === 0)
      continue;
    for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if(data[j][propertyName] === data[i][propertyName])
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass a parameter to your function to choose between the properties:

```
function isDuplicate(field) {            
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][field] === 0)
      continue;
    for(var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if(data[j][field] === data[i][field])
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

alert(isDuplicate('id'))
alert(isDuplicate('name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to rewrite that function so you only have one loop using `indexOf` to check for duplicates in a temporary array.

```
function hasDuplicate(type) {
  for (var dupe = [], i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    var val = data[i][type];
    if (dupe.indexOf(val) > -1) return true;
    if (val !== 0) dupe.push(val);
  }
  return false;
}

hasDuplicate('id');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ppgLva8e/2/)